# If you can reduce A to B, does that mean B reduces to A?

Tags: reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

If you can reduce A to B, does that mean B reduces to A?

Sorry for the stupid question. I think the answer should be yes, because if you can convert all yes-instances of A to yes-instances of B, then you basically just have to do the opposite to reduce yes-instances of B to yes-instances of A.

Comment: Which kind of reduction are you interested in?

Comment: For common notions of reduction, the answer is negative. A trivial problem (all instances are Yes instances or all of them are No instances) reduces to any non-trivial problem, but the reverse doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: I don't know, does it matter?

Comment: Probably the answer is "no" for any reasonable concept of reduction, but the reason of why the answer is "no" might be different. For example you can reduce the language $\emptyset$  to the language $\{0\}$ using many-one reductions but not vice-versa.  However if you consider Turing reductions the problems are reducible to each other (just ignore the oracle).

Comment: oh yes, I was refering to turing machine problems.

Comment: @SimonPedersen For problems involving Turing machines, there are also many many kinds of reductions. Please clarify *in the question* which kind or kinds of reductions you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

> basically just have to do the opposite

**Not all functions are surjective!**

It souds like you're thinking about some variant of *many-one reducibility*, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is reducible to $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ iff there is some "simple" (for now let's say that this means *polynomial-time computable*) function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x$ we have $$x\in A\iff f(x)\in B.$$ But what if this $f$ isn't surjective? For example, suppose $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B$ contains the set of even numbers. Then $x\mapsto 2x$ reduces $A$ to $B$, but how can I figure out whether $3\in B$ just by thinking about $A$? Since $3\not\in ran(f)$, the fact that $f$ lets us convert $A$-questions to $B$-questions doesn't help us here - **we can't always go backwards**.